# Type 'Observable<{}>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<boolean> | boolean '

Tags: typescript, angular

Im trying to follow [this tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#route-config), but I'm getting errors.

1. pathMatch: 'full'. I tried changing "*@angular/router*" to "*3.0.0-beta.2*", still the same issue.

My dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-beta.2",
    "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "nativescript-angular": "0.2.0",
    "tns-core-modules": "^2.1.0"
},
```

2. Type '*Observable<{}>' is not assignable to type 'Observable*', where it points to the line *'return o'*;

   ```
   canDeactivate(): Observable<boolean> | boolean {

   if (!this.crisis || this.crisis.name === this.editName) {

   return true;
   }
   let p = this.dialogService.confirm('Discard changes?');
   let o = Observable.fromPromise(p);
   return o;
   }
   ```

Can anyone guide me to fix these errors? thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You could try casting:

```
canDeactivate(): Observable<boolean> | boolean {

    if (!this.crisis || this.crisis.name === this.editName) {

        return true;
    }
    let p = this.dialogService.confirm('Discard changes?');
    let o = <Observable<boolean>>Observable.fromPromise(p);
    return o;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The compiler is complaining because the return value `o` is of type `Observable<{}>`. This is most likely because you are constructing an `Observable` from `p`, which resolves to type `Promise<{}>`. Double-check `dialogService.confirm()` and make sure its return value is of type `Promise<boolean>`.

If that doesn't work, you could try explicitly casting like @rinukkusu suggests.

Comment: thank you very much! Do you know how I could fix "pathMatch" error, suggestions from the internet don't seem to work.

Comment: @kenkulan What is the exact error you are receiving, from where, and in what circumstances?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and the problem was that i wasn,t injecting Authguard as a service on providers and also that i wasn,t put in routes an array in canActivated . Make sure that you have your AuthGuard as

```
`@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  logued: boolean = false;

  constructor(private rest: UsuarioService, private router: Router) {
    this.rest.getObservLogued().subscribe(res => {
      this.logued = res;
    });
  }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) : Observable<boolean|UrlTree>|Promise<boolean|UrlTree>|boolean|UrlTree  {
    let url: string = state.url;

    return this.checkLogin(url);
  }`
```

then in routes where you wish authguard set like this

```
`{ path: 'articulos', component: ArticuloComponent,

   canActivate: [AuthGuard] },`
```

and then check you are injecting as a service AuthGuard in app.module

```
providers : [AuthGuard]
```