# Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'Observable<boolean>'

Tags: angular, observable

I have that code

```
method(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this._http.get('sessionId=' + sessionId).map(res=> {
      if (res.status === "success") {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    });
}
```

But when `sessionId` is '' it throws an exception and console logs 401 error

and I add if inside that method:

```
method(): Observable<boolean> {
    if (sessionId === '')
      return false;
    return this._http.get('sessionId=' + sessionId).map(res=> {
      if (res.status === "success") {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    });
  }
```

But now I'm getting an error:

> Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'Observable'.

How can I solve that?

If I add `Observable<boolean> | boolean` then I'm getting error that

> Property 'map' does not exist on type 'boolean | Observable'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Type 'Observable<{}>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<boolean> | boolean '](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38299484/type-observable-is-not-assignable-to-type-observableboolean-boolean)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

```
method(): Observable<boolean> {
    if (sessionId === '')
      return false; // <<< obviously not an observable
```

This should do what you want

```
import { of, Observable } from 'rxjs';


method(): Observable<boolean> {
    if (sessionId === '')
      return of(false);
    }
    return this._http.get('sessionId=' + sessionId).map(res=> {
      if (res.status === "success") {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    });
  }
```

Comment: For Angular 6+ it is now `of()` instead of `Observable.of()`

Answer (score 14):

In addition to accepted answer I would add RxJs v6 case where `of` does not exist on `Observable` but could be imported directly from `rxjs`:

```
import { Observable, of as observableOf } from 'rxjs'; // since RxJs 6

method(): Observable<boolean> {
  if (sessionId === '')
    return observableOf(false);
  }
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For Angular users with STRICT TYPE setting, all other types seem to work OK (not that I tested ALL types... but number, and custom interfaces for example work without the added type declaration)

Using type boolean, this results in error:

```
_isBoolean$: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(false);
```

change to this:

```
_isBoolean$: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
```

this works too...

```
_isBoolean$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
_isBoolean$ = new BehaviorSubject(false);
```

However, as is quite clear, it removes...the...strict...typing ;)