# Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'void'. Angular 13 version

Tags: angular

I get the following error when i try to use subscribe. Please help me to fix this error

```
userLogin(){
  this.authService.userLogin(this.loginData)
  .subscribe ((value:boolean)=> {
    if(value){
        this.route.navigate(['/dashboard']);
    }
    else
    {
       alert('failed')
    }
    },error=>{
        alert('failed')
    })

 }
```

this is authService.userLogin function code. I think there is no any errors in this function code

```
       userLogin(userPayLoad: { username: string; password: string; }):Observable<boolean>{
     
       return  this.http.post("http://localhost:3000/auth/login", userPayLoad)

    .pipe(
        map( (value:any )=>{
            if(value){
                localStorage.setItem("access_token",value.access_token);
                localStorage.setItem("refresh_token",value.refresh_token);

                const decryptedUser= this.jwtHelper.decodeToken(value.access_token);
                console.log(decryptedUser);

                 const data={
                   access_token:value.access_token,
                   refresh_token:value.refresh_token,
                   username:decryptedUser.username,
                   userid: decryptedUser.sub,
                   tokenExpiration:decryptedUser.exp,

                };

                 this.userInfo.next(data);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        })

    )
 
}
```

[image: this is the error]

Comment: Post code of `this.authService.userLogin`

Comment: You get that error message, because this.authService.userLogin() doesn't return an observable. If we could see that functions code.

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava I posted a code of this.authService.userLogin.. can you show me the error

Comment: @will-cpu I added a code of this.authService.userLogin function. code can you help me

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can return of(true) or of(false) to return observable, Please check [Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'Observable<boolean>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42178383/type-boolean-is-not-assignable-to-type-observableboolean)

Comment: I can you show me how to do it please. I am new to angular

Comment: import { of, Observable } from 'rxjs';

method(): Observable<boolean> {
      return of(false);
    }